# Material UI Snackbar + Progress

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI (React) [Snackbar](https://material-ui.com/components/snackbars/#notistack) [notistack](https://iamhosseindhv.com/notistack/demos#action-for-all-snackbars).
I want to use [Material UI Progress](https://material-ui.com/components/progress/#circular-determinate) inside Snackbar. For example:

[image: Progress]

Inside this: 
[image]

I'm working with action Props but it's not working:

```
const action  =(key)=>{
        return(
            <Box>
                <CircularProgressWithLabel value={uploadPercentage}/>
            </Box>
        )
    }

enqueueSnackbar('MY TEXT', { variant: 'info',persist: true,action  });
```

Result (just shows 0%): 
[image: result]

but I am sure **uploadPercentage** changed...
for example *console.log(uploadPercentage)*:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

your `console.log` is 62% (for example),
the `CircularProgressWithLabel value` accept numbers, and 62% is not a number!

You are doing this:

```
<CircularProgressWithLabel value={'62%'} />
```

Correct way:

```
<CircularProgressWithLabel value={62} />
```

Comment: sorry, you are right, but I have in code exactly this: console.log(`${percent}%`). I think problem is in rerendering and action called just once...